# Will Sage, Oregano and Thyme grow well together in the same pot?

Tags: containers, herbs

I bought three herbs -- Sage, Oregano and Thyme -- from a grocery store each at a height of roughly 3-5 inches. I'd like to plant them in the same pot. Will they grow well together?

[This article](https://www.motherearthnews.com/real-food/which-herbs-grow-best-together-zbcz1506) suggests they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be grown nearby one another, they prefer the same conditions, but in a pot, the three together will quickly outgrow the container. Sage is a shrub that can get 2/3 feet wide by a couple of feet or more high; oregano spreads quite rapidly sideways and takes up a lot of room eventually; it makes quite a good groundcover in the border in a sunny spot, and usually needs digging out and splitting after a couple of years to control its spread. You've not mentioned which variety of Thyme - some just creep and spread sideways and don't get higher than 6 inches, others form a small to medium sized shrub,so its not whether they will upset one another if grown together,but more an issue of space over a year or so.